# PHP PDO select query return no result

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have created my database connection in connection.php and include it in insert.php. Then extend the class DBConnection class in constructor then create a function getData() where I ran a select query while i run my file i get only connection successful message . I tried all the possible options and search for a solution over stackoverflow and other places but failed.

This is my connection.php file

```
<?php

class DBConnection
{

    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->servername   = "localhost";
        $this->username     = "root";
        $this->password     = "";
        $this->dbname       = "pdo_test";
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            echo "connected successfully";
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

my insert.php

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');

class insertData extends DBConnection
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new DBConnection();
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $res = $stmt->execute();
        print_r($res->fetch());
    }
}

$id = new insertData();
echo $id->getData();

?>
```

Can any one point me my error in code? Thanks in advance

Note : Though there has no connection with it but still for more info i am using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think your class hierarchy isn't right, the problem is that in your `insertData` class, you have a constructor which creates a `DBConnection` instance and assigns it to `$this->conn`.  So when you refer to `$this->conn` you are referring to `DBConnection` instance and not a `PDO` object.  So your call to

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
```

will fail as `DBConnection` doesn't have a `prepare()` method.

If instead you remove the constructor and leave that to the base class, that will create the connection and assign it to `$this->conn`.  One thing you will have to change is `$conn` needs to be defined as `protected` to allow the derived class to access it.

```
protected $conn;
```

Also ensure that when you `execute()`, this just returns if the execute has succeeded, the result comes from the `fetch()`

```
class insertData extends DBConnection
{
    public function getData()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->fetch();
        print_r($res);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To check what's happening, can you try...

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$id = new insertData();
echo $id->getData();
```

Comment: yeah i was confused about it a bit ... but still same output

Comment: connected successfully
from db class

Comment: Can you look at the last bit of the answer to enable errors and see if something happens.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: insertData::$conn in /var/www/html/http/index.php on line 12

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/http/index.php:12 
 /var/www/html/http/index.php(22): insertData->getData() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/http/index.php on line 12

thanks for the idea at least i see the error now

Comment: Make sure that in connection.php, you change `protected $conn;`